# What is the proper way to annotate a function that can return two different types of objects?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I want to know how to annotate a function that can return two different objects. For example, many libraries will use a pattern similar to this:

```
// @flow
type MaybeResult = {| err: string |} | {| favoriteFruit: void |};

const getFavoriteFruitObj = (name): MaybeResult => 
  name === 'john' ? ({ favoriteFruit: 'apple' }) : ({ err: 'I only know peter\'s favorite fruit!' });
```

However, this returns the following error from flow:

```
5:   name === 'john' ? ({ favoriteFruit: 'apple' }) : ({ err: 'I only know peter\'s favorite fruit!' });
                                         ^ Cannot return `name === 'john' ? {...} : {...}` because string [1] is incompatible with undefined [2] in property `favoriteFruit`.
References:
5:   name === 'john' ? ({ favoriteFruit: 'apple' }) : ({ err: 'I only know peter\'s favorite fruit!' });
                                         ^ [1]
2: type MaybeResult = {| err: string |} | {| favoriteFruit: void |};
                                                            ^ [2]
```

What's the proper way to annotate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `|` is the correct way of creating [a Union](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/), i.e a way to indicate that values of a different set of types might be returned.

The error flow is reporting is because `favoriteFruit` has been annotated with `void` (`undefined`) but you then return a value with a property of type `string` from the function.

Maybe that should of been a [`Maybe`](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/maybe/) type? Maybe so. Changing it to `?string` [typechecks](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQAXAngBwKagLIENUAjTAJUwGcBXaZUAXlAG8AfUTAJ3YC5Rzl2AlgDsA5qGYBfcU1aQ8AN1iDkmAGLtKA5DwD8fQaPESA3IkQBjWEL6gRmZKoVKtajVoDyhAFb1QACiE8AFtMHn1hEQBKHnwiUgpqWjoAPlBEUFBAkPo6BgByL1gACyE80B1-RlA5RWVXTW1QPLx0dGhMMolI0B4-Ko5uJoBJUCtoVFAAayEEUCwVdgAdPPJqpzrqt2QAQk7I4yA) correctly.

Comment: Even without maybe, just string: `favoriteFruit: string`